# Unique id for user account in a machine(system user account)?

Tags: cpu, uniqueidentifier, mac-address

There are various ways to identify a system's unique id using Mac address, CPU id, motherboard id etc.

But is there any unique id to identify system's user account other than hostname or username?

And the same or equivalent identifier needs to be available in windows,ubuntu and mac osx.

-mathan

Comment: mac-address? Something which some machines may have multiples of, and something which may be transferred between machines or otherwise duplicated? Unusual definition of "unique" that I wasn't previously aware of...

Comment: Yeah, there are some identifiers which can be fakable. But I mentioned just for the sake of reference to generic system level identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something cross-platform, the most straightforward thing to do is to generate a guid and store in an admin/root owned file. Here's an example of using a GUID from tivoli documentation.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itsmfdt.doc%2Fans5000075.htm

You could then optionally store these GUIDs in a database when the computers are provisioned, or after the fact, either way.